# Use Leanback UI on Mobile/Tablet for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-tv, television, leanback

I am currently developing a mobile app for phone/tablet devices that looks like the Leanback sample app. I really like the Leanback UI used for Android TV.

Unfortunately, on Android studio, I can't use Leanback with mobile projects.

Is there some kind of customized version of Leanback than can be used on other devices?

***P.S ***: ***I found [this](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialLeanBack) project, but I enable to import it on Android Studio, it tells me that I don't have the right SDK version.***

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this project you found is fairly old and is using older dependencies. You would need to go into your SDK manager and install SDK version 22 (Lollipop MR1).

You could also fork the project and update it to use API version 24 so it works with your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="true" />
```

Just place this, it runs in mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my fork, I fixed the build issue and updated the build configuration to android 30.

https://github.com/moaz-cliqz/MaterialLeanBack